# Can I use derived attribute for defining another derived attribute in the same sql command?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql and wondering if the following command is valid.

```
SELECT price, age, price * age AS PA, (PA-age)*age AS PS FROM P ;
```

As shown above, can I use PA defined above to define PS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT p.*, (PA-age)*age AS PS
FROM (SELECT price, age, price * age AS PA
      FROM P
     ) p;
```

This is a SQL limitation, not specifically a MySQL limitation.

Comment: What does p.* mean here?

Comment: @user7755336 . . . I means all the columns from the subquery (derived table) which has the alias `p`.

Answer (score 0):

> can I use PA defined above to define PS?

No. An alias defined within the `SELECT` clause, can't be used to form another column in that `SELECT` clause. The expressions for the `SELECT` clause must each refer to terms already defined elsewhere.

Fortunately, that “elsewhere” can be another result set, such as a sub-query. Assuming your `p` table has a primary key, maybe the `id` field:

```sql
SELECT
    p.price AS price,
    p.age AS age,
    pa.price_age AS price_age,
    ((pa.price_age - p.age) * p.age) AS price_schmurt
FROM p
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            p.id AS id,
            (p.price * p.age) AS price_age
        FROM p
        ) AS pa
        ON pa.id = p.id
```